# Exist's someting like execSQL() but for select sentences?

Tags: android, sqlite

I like execSQL because i can do this:

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Usuarios (codigo, nombre) VALUES (1, 'pedro')");
```

Does there exist something similar (which only needs a string as parameter) that can process SELECT statements and return a Cursor object with the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not exactly what you want, but is very similar:

```
public Cursor rawQuery (String sql, String[] selectionArgs);
```

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)

Just use '?' during the query for the values you want later to substitute with the String array in the correct order.

Comment: can i use Raw Query to make Inserts also? –

Comment: I don't think so, as a Query is not an Insert. You can keep on using execSQL whenever you want to insert something in the DB.

Answer (score 1):

You should learn to use the query method, there is a reason why they added it to the frameworks. Also look up [SQLiteQueryBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html).

Comment: i prefeer to find something that achieve my needs, thanks btw

Comment: Learn to use the tools available, to achieve your solution, don't fixate on one thing. I don't see why you have any reason to use a "raw query" when a simple query would work the exact same way. If you look at the document of the SqliteDatabase object, you'll see there i utlity methods to do what you want. Its as **SIMPLE** as just learning to use them.. instead of wasting your time with what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Raw Query. In Raw query you can put string of SQL query.

Comment: can i use Raw Query to make Inserts also?